# Does tiny bit of nasal mucus/booger invalidate wudu?

Tags: salat, fiqh, wudu, fatwa

I did wudu and while doing it I saw that a little something had come out of my nose but I forgot to remove it. After I did wudu I went and prayed isha and only remembered it then. Now I am not sure if my prayer is valid

Answer (score 0):

Removing mucus from the nose does not invalidate wudhu and neither does clotted blood. Only flowing blood or pus from the nose invalidates wudhu and anything else can be removed from the nose such as mucus.

NOTE: THIS IS ONLY REGARDING THE NOSE AS THERE ARE OTHER BREAKERS OF WUDHU